# Length[Range[5]] vs Length@Range[5]

Tags: functions, syntax, documentation

I've looked all over the Wolfram Documentation and done various searches on the web and this site and I can't find an explanation of the single "@" symbol as a means of applying functions.

It seems to perform as an alternate syntax to the full form of a function.  I've used it with my own function definitions and with Length, and it seems to work.

What's unnerving to me is that I cannot find a clear explanation in the documentation, any tips on how to better find this stuff in the documentation would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/UseShorthandNotations.html

Comment: More generally, when there is a symbol you don't understand, highlight it and press F1, bringing you to the documentation. In this case, it brings you to Prefix, which is the full name of the @ symbol.

Comment: @bills Generally, selecting it and pressing F1 works, and opens the documentation page of the corresponding function.  But this case is a bit more special. `Prefix` is not the full name of full form of `@`.  In fact `@` does not have a "full form" at all. `(f@x)` is precisely equivalent to `(f[x])` in every case. They parse to the same internal representation.

Comment: Thank you all.  I'll get better at searching.

Comment: Since this is a duplicate, should I just delete it?  I'm not sure what the etiquette is.